# DocuSign Power Apps Custom Connector not working

Tags: oauth-2.0, docusignapi, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I am setting up the DocuSign rest connector in power apps. I have other API's that working well this same way.

I want to get this setup to sweep completed files on a scheduled.

I started by going through this tutorial and tried the same setup. But when I try to test the connector I don't get prompted for credentials. We use SSO - so the window comes up and goes away without an error message.

https://www.docusign.com.au/blog/get-the-flow-sending-docusign-envelopes-microsoft-power-automate

I then tried to create a connection in in power automate Data/Connections and get an error message after entering my dev credentials. The clientid (integration key) and the secret match.

OAuth2 authorization flow failed for service 'Generic Oauth 2'. OAuth 2 sign in failed to exchange code for access token. Client ID and secret sent in form body.. Response status code=NotFound. Response body: { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" } Client ID and secret sent in Basic authorization header.. Response status code=NotFound. Response body: { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }

The setup looks correct. It seems like a reference problem = like the production account and the developer account are not in sync or something. I have the same email address for both production and developer accounts and we use SSO - maybe its trying to reference production and not the developer account when its logging in? Just guessing.

I have a ticket with them, but they have note been able to help so far and they are on AEST time and I won't be able to get a response back from them for another couple of days :(

(I tried using the DocuSign Git repo API to create the connection as well - same problem)

Anyone have problems like this or know a solution? Anything else I can look at. This seems all straight forward -standard OAuth setup.

Using this setup like in the article for the demo (dev) account.

DEMO:
IKey: Integration Key [captured earlier]

Secret Key: Secret Key [captured earlier]

Authorization URL (DEMO): https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth

Token URL (DEMO): https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token

Refresh URL (DEMO): https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token

Scope: signature extended

Comment: What URL do you use for the OAuth?

Comment: @InbarGazit https://account-d.docusign.com like in the article

Answer (score 1):

This will connect to a single DocuSign user (like a "service account"). It will not prompt each user for their credentials. You will need 1 generic user setup within your DocuSign account, without SSO (you can setup an exception user in DocuSign admin. This is best practice when setting up SSO as a fallback in case SSO fails to login as well).

The envelope will be sent from that generic user, not the actual user. This is common practice with some "system level" integrations.

Also, are you connecting a DocuSign "demo" or production account?
I ask because there's two connectors for power automate - "DocuSign" (for production) and "Docusign Demo" (for demo). I would recommend doing it all in demo first, as the "client id" (aka "integration key") needs to go through a go-live process to be promoted from demo to prod (see the link in the guide).

Comment: This is for demo. Just using my credentials and dev account to test. This is a custom connector. Not their built in connector. We need to get documents on a schedule. Webhooks are not good for what we are doing. I do this with other services and works 100%. I’m trying to see if their is a problem with their service in how it’s authenticating. I’m going to create a different account for development to see if that might work. Nothing else does.

Comment: Are you trying to send an envelope (steps in my blog)? Or are you trying to use the webhook to capture updates from DocuSign (eg. Archiving completed documents)?

Comment: I am looking to grab updates on a cycle.. But not with a webhook incase something is missing. I tried use the git DocuSign api first. And found this authentication issue. Then I tried this tutorial exactly and have the same auth issue. I have built this myself a couple years ago in .Net and was polling on a task, but I needed to reduce this down to the custom connector for other IT folks that don’t know how to code.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly, archive in SharePoint? The standard DocuSign trigger might be what you need, can you at least try it to see if you get any authentication ossues, more info https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=gqy1619537336307&topicId=bgr1619538245217.html&_LANG=enus

Comment: I tried it. It doesn’t have the method available to get envelopes.

Comment: So authentication works for the built-in method, so must be something in the custom connector. Try using the standard step instead of get envelope method. All "completed" envelopes trigger the envelope, use a 'get document's to get the file, use a 'parse json' to get the envelope data.

Comment: I am doing the webhook trigger when completed. But it it’s not reliable enough for archiving hr documents. I want to run a sweep job in case it misses a document.

Comment: Is the "resource not found" error occuring during authentication? Or on the "get" method? Can you try following my guide to add a "send envelope" method to see if that works?

Comment: Well, I retried this morning and I didn't get the error message. Everything was basically the same with the setup. It creates connections now. Not sure what the issue was.